# javascript - not able to execute the promise from array one by one

Tags: javascript, reactjs, promise

I found that I cannot resolve the promises one by one.

This is my code

```
const promises = mkt.map((marketItem) => {
  return context.program.account.chain
    .fetch(marketItem[0].instrument)
    .then((instrumentRes) => {
      return Test(context, marketItem[0]).then(
        testResult => {
          return Promise.all([
            functionA(),
            functionB(),
          ]).then((result) => {
            return result
          });
        }
      );
    });
});
console.log(promises)
for (let i=0; i < promises.length; i++) {
  const val = await promises[i]();
  console.log(val);
}
```

error

```
promises[i]() is not a function
```

Why is that?How can I solve it?

Comment: But you could probably do `Promise.all(promises).then(resolvedPromises => { .... })`, right?

Comment: @Drew Reese that's was right, but I am working on some real time update stuff. if I use `Promise.all` it will throw error `Too many request`, so I want to do it one by one to see the effect

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> `promises[i]() is not a function`

Correct, this is because `promises` is an array of `Promise` objects, not functions.

You can dump this `promises` array into `Promise.all` and wait for them all to resolve.

```
Promise.all(promises)
  .then(resolvedPromises => {
    // handle array of resolved promises
  });
```

> but I am working on some real time update stuff. If I use `Promise.all`
> it will throw error `Too many request`, so I want to do it one by one to
> see the effect

For this then I think you want to iterate on the `mkt` array and wait for each created Promise to resolve. Refactor the mapping callback into a standalone function that you can manually invoke within the for-loop, awaiting the the Promise to settle.

```
const request = (marketItem) => {
  return context.program.account.chain
    .fetch(marketItem[0].instrument)
    .then((instrumentRes) => Test(context, marketItem[0]))
    .then(testResult => Promise.all([functionA(), functionB()]))
    .then((result) => result);
}

for (let i=0; i < mkt.length; i++) {
  try {
    const val = await request(mkt[i]);
    console.log(val);
  } catch(error) {
    // handle any error
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Just removing the `()` from the await call should already work.

```
  const val = await promises[i];
```

However keep in mind that all the promises have already been "started" (I don't know a better word for that) at that point and you're just retrieving the results or an error with the `await` call.